# PHP fill JSON array error

Tags: php, json

I have a some simple JSON:

```
"feed" : [
    {
        "title" : "some title",
        "link" : "http://somelink.com",
        "image" : {
            "url" : "http://somelink.com/image.png",
            "offset" : "0.0"
        }
    }
]
```

In my PHP i'm adding a new feed item to my JSON. I can populate everything fine except my 'image' item.

I'm using:

```
array_push($json['feed'], 'image' => array('url' => 'http://gijfsdf.com/', 'offset' => '0.0'));
```

but that gives me a syntax error: Parse error: `syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) on line 18`

Comment: The `'image' => …` needs to be wrapped in an `array(…)` construct itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to put image inside array like

```
array_push($json['feed'], array('image' => array('url' => 'http://gijfsdf.com/', 'offset' => '0.0')));
```